# Background doesn't repeat to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to do a slider menu, i have a div with a tape background, all is working fine when it's animating to the left by the background-repeat, but when it is animating to the right and it get to the left border of the background it get disappears because background-repeat doesn't repeat to the left, just to the right.. There's way to make the background repeat to the left?

And the list inside the "slider" div doesn't move at the same velocity of "slider" div

**Here is the HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "PruebaIndex.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var mode = 0; // 0 Left - 1 Right
            autoSlider();
            function autoSlider(){
                mode = 0;
                $("#slider").animate({left: "-=60px", width: "+=60px"}, 'slow', 'linear', autoSlider);
            }
            function slideLeft(){
                mode = 1;
                $("#slider").animate({left: "+=60px", width: "-=60px"}, 'slow', 'linear', slideLeft);
            }
            $("#slider").mouseover(function(){
                $("#slider").stop();
            });
            $("#slider").mouseout(function(){
                if(mode === 0)
                    autoSlider();
                else
                    slideLeft();
            });
            $("#Left").mouseover(function(){
                $("#slider").stop();
                autoSlider();
            });
            $("#Right").mouseover(function(){
                $("#slider").stop();
                slideLeft();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "wrapper">
        <div id = "slider">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id = "Left">
            Left
        </div>
        <div id = "Right">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**And the CSS code**

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#slider {
padding: 0;
left: 0px;
background-color: black;
background-image: url("http://s11.postimg.org/msh93rl8z/Tira_Fotografica.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
width: 800px;
height: 304px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
width: 800px;
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
}

#Left {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
color: white;
background-color: black;
margin-top: -200px;
margin-left: -100px;
}

#Right {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
color: white;
background-color: black;
margin-top: -200px;
margin-left: 800px;
}

#slider ul {
list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
background-color: white;
margin: 50px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

**I tried to put the code on JSFiddle but it doesn't run..**
**Sorry for my bad english**

Comment: As stated in the answer, what is being animated is the div being shifted, and it has a `width` value when it shifted close to that value it will stop, try to animate repeated pieces of the image with css sprite sheet http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps

Answer (score 0):

it works. see here: https://jsfiddle.net/cLv4hLfy/

take a look at the #slider element.

this values are annoying ;-)

```
<div style="left: -5863.5px; width: 6663.8px; overflow: hidden;" id="slider">
```

left is decreasing and width is getting bigger and bigger.
when the slider goes to the opposite direction left gets bigger and width convergates to `0px`.

[EDIT]: so the background is not animated. the div is animated. what about fix the div and animate something in the div. you could do something also with background position when its repeated.